# CSS - font-face browser render error

Tags: css, font-face, google-font-api

I'm using google.com/fonts in my project.
I need Roboto Condensed font.

But in all of my browsers there is some artifacts above letters.
Please, see example (saved from google page): [example of issue from google-fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTQvE.jpg)

**UPDATE:** [this is zoomed 14px font, as you can see there is 1px dot above each letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKRBd.jpg)

Now, I found that letters shows correctly in big sizes, and errors only with few sizes (12px, 14px, 16px, 22px).

This error is in all browsers on my Windows 8 (FF, IE, Chrome, Safari, Opera).
Somewhere I found that this is because of old display port drivers, but I have latest ATI drivers (from march, 2014).

And also, this trouble shows on some PC. On others all fonts clear and easy to read.

Did anyone had same errors? How to fix them? May be there is some CSS3 tricks for this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeh Roboto looks exactly like i've used it

Comment: Look at 16px font size - I've wrote that big letters are OK, and smaller is with artefacts.

Answer (score 0):

Some fonts do result in unexpected rendering. Mostly, webkit broswers. They some times renders font differently at different font-sizes. 
If you are using @font-face, you can try this trick I used when using 'Exo' font. I faced same issue like you and using this solved my problem. And try to generate font-face from fontsquirrel.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'exoregular';
    src: url('path to file/exo-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('path to file/exo-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('path to file/exo-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('path to file/exo-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('path to file/exo-regular-webfont.svg#exoregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

**The fix ! simply ADD this block BELOW the above block**

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'exoregular';
            src: url('path to file/exo-regular-webfont.svg#exoregular') format('svg');
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that you said, but it not helps :(
Your solution may helps only for webkit browsers and for android tablets. But for me - this trouble is in all browsers (not only webkit).